# How to Lock drawer for specific page using drawerNavigation [react-navigation][react-native]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is my drawerNavigation :

```js
const DashboardStack = StackNavigator({
        Dashboard: {
            screen: Dashboard
        },
    }, {
        headerMode: 'screen',
    });

const DetailsformStack = StackNavigator({
    Detailsform: {
        screen: Detailsform
    },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none'
});

const OtpStack = StackNavigator({
    Otp: {
        screen: Otp,
        drawer: {
            lockMode: 'locked-closed'
        }
    },
    }, {
        headerMode: 'none'
});

const MobilenumberStack = StackNavigator({
    Mobilenumber: {
        screen: Mobilenumber
    },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none'
});

const DrawerviewStack = StackNavigator({
    Drawerview: {
        screen: Drawerview
    },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none'
});

const ExamsheetStack = StackNavigator({
    Examsheet: {
        screen: Examsheet
    },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none'
});

const TopicStack = StackNavigator({
    Topic: {
        screen: Topic
    },
}, {
    headerMode: 'screen'
});

const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
    Otp: {
        screen: OtpStack,
    },
    Dashboard: {
        screen: DashboardStack,
    },
    Detailsform: {
        screen: DetailsformStack,
    },
    Mobilenumber: {
        screen: MobilenumberStack,
    },
    Drawerview: {
        screen: DrawerviewStack,
    },
    Examsheet: {
        screen: ExamsheetStack,
    },
    Topic: {
        screen: TopicStack,
    }
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Mobilenumber',
    contentComponent: Drawerview,

    lockMode: 'locked-closed'
});
```

export default DrawerStack

How can i add lock mode `lockMode` to specific page.

i tried adding
 `drawer: {lockMode: 'locked-closed'}` 
in both components page and drawerNavigation page but it doesnt work.

Does react navigation have a lock mode feature or do i need to disable the swipe gesture?

If there is no feature then let me know how to disable swipe gesture for a particular component or page.

Comment: have you got solution?

Answer (score 8):

[martnu](https://github.com/martnu) gave a [patch](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/793/files) for this, but not yet merged.
I tried to patch it manually and works perfectly.

It works with only change of two files: (reference to this page https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/pull/793/files)

> 1. *react-navigation/src/TypeDefinition.js*,

copy below code into `NavigationDrawerScreenOptions`, right above `NavigationRouteConfigMap`, put into declaration of `NavigationDrawerScreenOptions`:

```js
drawerLockMode?: 'unlocked' | 'locked-close' | 'locked-open',
```

> 2. *react-navigation/src/views/DrawerView.js*,

copy below code into `render()` right before function return:

```js
const options = this.props.router.getScreenOptions(
    addNavigationHelpers({
        state: this._screenNavigationProp.state,
        dispatch: this._screenNavigationProp.dispatch,
    }),
    this.props.screenProps,
);
```

and copy below code into returning `<DrawLayout>` props, right after `ref`:

```js
drawerLockMode={options.drawerLockMode || 'unlocked'}
```

> Usage:

you can disable the drawer on any screen by just adding:

```js
navigationOptions: {
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
}
```

and to enable drawer:

```js
navigationOptions: {
  drawerLockMode: 'unlocked'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I also have faced this on react-navigation v2. as written in [drawer docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#a-drawer-has-a-stack-inside-of-it-and-you-want-to-lock-the-drawer-on-certain-screens)
the solution can be to define navigation options right after routes initialization and it forbids to display Drawer navigator in defined routes.

My routes looks like

```
const RoutesStack = StackNavigator({
    Authentication: {
        screen: Authentication,
    },
    {...}
});
```

And Options added, bellow routes.

```js
RoutesStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    name = (navigation.state.index !== undefined ? navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index] : navigation.state.routeName)
    let drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed'
    if (name.routeName != 'Authentication' && name.routeName != 'Signup') {
        drawerLockMode = 'unlocked'
    }

    return {
        drawerLockMode,
    };
}
```

Comment: This really helped me, Thanks @NeriusJok

Comment: This is not working for me in iOS and Android.Can please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55811507/disableopengesture-hiding-is-not-working-navigation-drawer-react-native

Comment: And what is "name" here in RoutesStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

Comment: Where can we set header: null in above navigationOptions?

Comment: this answer helped and gave an idea to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Now, things have been changed in react-navigation version-5.

`swipeEnabled` is used to lock the drawer in `Drawer.Screen` inside the `Drawer.Navigator`

Visit https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#swipeenabled

Please see the below code:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import React from "react";
import { Sidebar } from "./SideBar";
import { ScreenWithDrawerEnabled } from "./ScreenWithDrawerEnabled";
import { ScreenWithDrawerDisabled } from "./ScreenWithDrawerDisabled";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const DashboardDrawerNavigator = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator
    initialRouteName={ScreenWithDrawerEnabled}
    drawerPosition="left"
    drawerType="slide"
    drawerContent={props => <Sidebar {...props} />}
  >
    <Drawer.Screen
      name={'ScreenWithDrawerEnabled'}
      component={ScreenWithDrawerEnabled}
    />
    <Drawer.Screen
      options={({ route, navigation }) => {
        return {
          swipeEnabled: false,
        };
      }}
      name={'ScreenWithDrawerDisabled'}
      component={ScreenWithDrawerDisabled}
    />

  </Drawer.Navigator>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show Drawer navigato for specific page by adding the following

```
.......
  Dashboard :{
      screen: DashboardStack,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        drawerLockMode: 'unlocked',
      })
  }
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Ans of [@ajith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300429/6192084) helped me!

This is what my code looks like:

```
const DrawerStack = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: Home,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
            })
            },
        Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard},
        .....
    }, 
DrawerNavigatorConfig)
```

Hope this helps! :)