# How to disable sideMenu on current window

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

How to disable sideMenu on current window even user swipe right or left on the screen

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 2.0.2106
- React Native version: 0.52.2
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): both
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): all

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by setting the following configuration,

```
Navigation.push(this.props.componentId, {
  component: {
    name: screen,
    options: {sideMenu: {left: {enabled: false}}},
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting navigationOptions of that page by adding the following code to the Component code.

```
static navigationOptions = {
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
}
```

More detailed explanation can be found in the below linked SO answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45160191/6435908

Comment: I think you solution is worked with react-native-navigation V1 not the V2 version.