# disableOpenGesture hiding is not working Navigation Drawer react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer, gesture

We are using Navigation Drawer in our application to show side menu.
In a few of the screens we don't want to show this navigation drawer once user tried to do left/right gestures.

So, for that, we are trying to hide a particular screen - gestures/navigationdrawer -  but it's not working.
When the user swipes (left/right) the drawer still opens.

```java
    const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
      {
        // Drawer: { screen: Drawer },
        Register: {
          screen: Register,
          navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            drawerLockMode: "locked-closed",
          })
        },
        TabHome: { screen: TabHome },
        Album: { screen: Album },
        offlineContent: { screen: offlineContent },
        changePassword: { screen: changePassword },
        Player: {screen: Player},
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "TabHome",
        // header: null
      }
    );
```

We have tried both `drawerLockMode:"locked-closed"` and     `disableOpenGesture: true`
but nothing is working.

Note: I am using `"react-navigation": "^3.0.9"` version

Any suggestions to disable navigation drawer being opened by gestures?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code?

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
      {
        // Drawer: { screen: Drawer },
        Register: {
          screen: Register
        },
        TabHome: { screen: TabHome },
        Album: { screen: Album },
        offlineContent: { screen: offlineContent },
        changePassword: { screen: changePassword },
        Player: {screen: Player},
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: "TabHome",
        // header: null
      }
    );
AppNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const navigationOptions = {};
  if (getCurrentRouteName(navigation.state) === 'Register') {
    navigationOptions.drawerLockMode = 'locked-closed';
  }
  return navigationOptions;
};
```

OR If your react-navigation version is V2,

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator({
    Register: Register,
},
    {
        drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'
    }
);
```

getCurrentRouteName function

```js
getCurrentRouteName(navState) {

    if (navState.hasOwnProperty('index')) {
        this.getCurrentRouteName(navState.routes[navState.index])
    } else {
        console.log("Current Route Name:", navState.routeName)
        // can then save this to the state (I used redux)
        store.dispatch(setCurrentRouteName(navState.routeName))
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain first method, And what it will do? We are doing disable that gesture in stacknavigator.

Comment: You can add AppNavigator.navigationOptions under the defined  AppNavigator code.

Comment: You mean I have to add all the screens which are need to avoid gestures?

Comment: getCurrentRouteName getting undefined

Comment: Still getCurrentRouteName showing undefined in AppNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
method

Comment: Does it say that GetCurrentRouteName cannot be found?

Comment: 'getCurrentRouteName' is not defined.eslint(no-undef)

Comment: where is getCurrentRouteName function?

Comment: You have given getCurrentRouteName(navState) {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192318/discussion-between-anilkumar-ios-developer-and-hong-develop).